# Running Total of Ones Count in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm writing a code where we need to find all the ones in a character and display them as a total. However, the code updates the total for each character pressed, rather than adding all previous ones counts.

Help would be appreciated.

```
namespace ica5_eventdriven
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Enabled = true;
            lblKeyCode.Text = e.KeyChar.ToString();

            listBox1.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(Convert.ToByte(e.KeyChar), 2));

            List<byte> byteList = new List<byte>();
            byteList.Add((byte)e.KeyChar);

            byte binaryVal = Convert.ToByte(e.KeyChar);
            int ones = 0;
            int zeros = 0;

            foreach (byte val in byteList)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                {
                    if ((binaryVal & 1) == 1)
                    {
                        ones++;
                        lblOnesCount.Text = ones.ToString();
                    }
                    else
                        zeros++;

                    binaryVal >>= 1;

                }
            }
        }

        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: They don't accumulate value because you are initialising `ones` and `zeroes` to 0 every time method `Form1_KeyPress` runs. You need to declare those variables and initialise them outside the method.

Comment: It works! Thank you!

Comment: Do you need to find the total number of 1's and 0's count that exists in your list ??